# Android: Custom layout Dialog; how the custom background button is strange?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a custom DialogFragment with a layout with 2 buttons:

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/negative_button"
   style="@style/DialogButton"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
   android:text="negative" />
```

I've defined a style for these buttons named "DialogButton":

```
<style name="DialogButton">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_medium</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/theme_accent_1</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">64dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/dialog_button_corner</item>
</style>
```

Background "dialog_button_corner" definition:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/dialog_button_pressed" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_focused="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/dialog_button_pressed" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

And when I press on these buttons, there is a **strange appearance** on the background button:

- no corner radius
- a border appears (on this screenshot at the right)

Could you help me guys?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Lollipop and above, there is a stateListAnimator, that elevates your view while clicked. Try setting this attribute, to remove the stateListAnimator:

```
    android:stateListAnimator="@null"
```

**Bonus:**
Create your own stateListAnimator.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true">
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:propertyName="translationZ"
        android:valueTo="@dimen/buttonClickedElevation"
        android:valueType="floatType" />
</item>

<item>
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:propertyName="translationZ"
        android:valueTo="0dp"
        android:valueType="floatType" />
</item>
```